# Unbalanced Disk Usage Among Nodes in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I've built up a CouchDB cluster of 4 nodes to store the tweets I retrieved

The cluster was configured to have 8 shards and keep 3 copies of each document

```
[cluster]
q=8
r=2
w=2
n=3
```

I haven't added any views or additional indexes and the size of the database shown in Fauxton is `4.3 GB`

However, CouchDB is taking up exceptionally large disk space in one of the nodes

```
$ ansible -i hosts -s -m shell -a 'du /vol/couchdb/shards/* -sh' couchdb
crake.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
363M    /vol/couchdb/shards/00000000-1fffffff
990M    /vol/couchdb/shards/20000000-3fffffff
17G     /vol/couchdb/shards/40000000-5fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/60000000-7fffffff
359M    /vol/couchdb/shards/80000000-9fffffff
989M    /vol/couchdb/shards/a0000000-bfffffff
12G     /vol/couchdb/shards/c0000000-dfffffff
1.6G    /vol/couchdb/shards/e0000000-ffffffff

darter.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/00000000-1fffffff
367M    /vol/couchdb/shards/20000000-3fffffff
1001M   /vol/couchdb/shards/40000000-5fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/60000000-7fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/80000000-9fffffff
364M    /vol/couchdb/shards/a0000000-bfffffff
998M    /vol/couchdb/shards/c0000000-dfffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/e0000000-ffffffff

bustard.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
1004M   /vol/couchdb/shards/00000000-1fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/20000000-3fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/40000000-5fffffff
365M    /vol/couchdb/shards/60000000-7fffffff
1001M   /vol/couchdb/shards/80000000-9fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/a0000000-bfffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/c0000000-dfffffff
364M    /vol/couchdb/shards/e0000000-ffffffff

avocet.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/00000000-1fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/20000000-3fffffff
368M    /vol/couchdb/shards/40000000-5fffffff
999M    /vol/couchdb/shards/60000000-7fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/80000000-9fffffff
1.4G    /vol/couchdb/shards/a0000000-bfffffff
364M    /vol/couchdb/shards/c0000000-dfffffff
1001M   /vol/couchdb/shards/e0000000-ffffffff
```

In `crake.couchdb.cloud`, two of the shards, `40000000-5fffffff` and `c0000000-dfffffff`, are far larger than others.

I once tried deleting those large shards in `crake.couchdb.cloud` and waited CouchDB itself to rebuild. The disk usage was balanced after the rebuild however it gradually went unbalanced again after I started adding new documents to the database.

I'm using `MD5(tweet[id_str])` as the document ID. Could this be the reason of the issue?

I feel really confused about this as I think even if I've made any mistakes, it should have eaten up the resources of 3 different nodes as the data are replicated across the cluster.

Please help, thanks.

***UPDATE***

Later I deleted all the VPS instances and rebuilt the cluster with 3 CouchDB nodes, namely `Avocet`, `Bustard` and `Crake`. The new cluster configuration is as following:

```
[cluster]
q=12
r=2
w=2
n=2
```

Before the rebuilding, I replicated all the data to an alternative CouchDB instance so I could transfer them back after it's done. The disk usage was balanced after the restoration.

Additionally, I introduced a HAProxy on the 4th node, namely `Darter`, as a load balancer.

So this time, all my twitter retrievers send their requests to the balancer. However the disk usage became unbalanced again, and it was exactly the 3rd node `Crake` which took up much more space.

```
bustard.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vdc         81G  9.4G   68G  13% /vol

avocet.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vdc         81G  9.3G   68G  13% /vol

crake.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vdc         81G   30G   48G  39% /vol
```

The database size is only `4.2 GB` and `Crake` used approximately 7 times larger than that!

I'm completely clueless now...

***UPDATE 2***

The `_dbs` info from all the nodes

```
crake.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
{
    "db_name": "_dbs",
    "update_seq": "11-g2wAAAABaANkABtjb3VjaGRiQGNyYWtlLmNvdWNoZGIuY2xvdWRsAAAAAmEAbgQA_____2phC2o",
    "sizes": {
        "file": 131281,
        "external": 8313,
        "active": 9975
    },
    "purge_seq": 0,
    "other": {
        "data_size": 8313
    },
    "doc_del_count": 0,
    "doc_count": 7,
    "disk_size": 131281,
    "disk_format_version": 6,
    "data_size": 9975,
    "compact_running": false,
    "instance_start_time": "0"
}

avocet.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
{
    "db_name": "_dbs",
    "update_seq": "15-g2wAAAABaANkABxjb3VjaGRiQGF2b2NldC5jb3VjaGRiLmNsb3VkbAAAAAJhAG4EAP____9qYQ9q",
    "sizes": {
        "file": 159954,
        "external": 8313,
        "active": 10444
    },
    "purge_seq": 0,
    "other": {
        "data_size": 8313
    },
    "doc_del_count": 0,
    "doc_count": 7,
    "disk_size": 159954,
    "disk_format_version": 6,
    "data_size": 10444,
    "compact_running": false,
    "instance_start_time": "0"
}

bustard.couchdb.cloud | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
{
    "db_name": "_dbs",
    "update_seq": "15-g2wAAAABaANkAB1jb3VjaGRiQGJ1c3RhcmQuY291Y2hkYi5jbG91ZGwAAAACYQBuBAD_____amEPag",
    "sizes": {
        "file": 159955,
        "external": 8313,
        "active": 9999
    },
    "purge_seq": 0,
    "other": {
        "data_size": 8313
    },
    "doc_del_count": 0,
    "doc_count": 7,
    "disk_size": 159955,
    "disk_format_version": 6,
    "data_size": 9999,
    "compact_running": false,
    "instance_start_time": "0"
}
```

Comment: It sounds very strange to me too, I think you need to look at which databases have the large shards, what their _dbs entries say and whether their shards are small on the other nodes or nonexistent.

Comment: @lossleader I just deleted the whole cluster and rebuilt a new one with 3 nodes (2 doc replicas). Additionally, I introduced HAProxy to the system as a balancer. Again, after transferring all data back from an alternative CouchDB instance, all ok. Started retrieving new tweets, unbalanced.

Comment: @lossleader And it seems that it's always the 3rd node which takes a lot more storage. Currently the DB size is `4.2 GB` however the 3rd node has already used up `30 GB`, which is approx 7 times larger! I feel really lost now

Comment: @lossleader I've just pasted the `_dbs` from all nodes but frankly I do not understand some of the metrics in it. The node `Crake` that's eating up storage has the same `data_size` as others however the `disk_size` is rather greater.